# Does reflection class have implicit method __toString() in php?

Tags: php, class, oop, tostring

I am reading [https://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-4th/dp/0672329166](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)
. And there is OOP chapter where I have implemented the `page` class (code below), and then in another script try to make an instance through `Reflection("Page")`, where in turn trying to `echo` that class (via the implicit method `__toString()`, just as in the book:

*page.php*:

```
<?php

class Page
{
    public $content;
    public function setContent(string $c)
    {
        $this->content = $c;
    }
    public $title = "Papaluz Corp";
    public function setTitle(string $t)
    {
        $this->title = $t;
    }
    public $keywords = " Papaluz Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation,
    some of my best friends are search engines";
    public function setKeywords(string $k)
    {
        $this->keywords = $k;
    }
    public $buttons = [
        'Home' => 'home.php',
        'Contact' => 'contact.php',
        'Services' => 'services.php',
        'About' => 'about.php'
    ];
    public function setButtons(array $b)
    {
        $this->buttons = $b;
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo "<html>\n<head>\n";
        $this->displayTitle();
        $this->displayKeywords();
        $this->displayStyles();
        echo "</head>\n<body>\n";
        $this->displayHeader();
        $this->displayMenu($this->buttons);
        echo $this->content;
        $this->displayFooter();
        echo "</body>\n</html>\n";
    }
    public function displayTitle()
    {
        echo '<title>' . $this->title . '</title>';
    }
    public function displayKeywords()
    {
        echo '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $this->keywords . '"/>';
    }
    public function displayStyles()
    {
?>
        <link href="/2/default/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php
    }
    public function displayHeader()
    {
    ?>
        <header>
            <img src='/data/img/pap_white.png' width="130" height="130">
            <h1>Papaluz Consulting</h1>
        </header>
    <?php
    }
    public function displayMenu(array $buttons)
    {
        echo '<nav>';
        foreach ($buttons as $name => $url) {
            $this->displayButton($name, $url, !$this->isUrlCurrentPage($url));
        }
        echo "</nav>\n";
    }
    public function displayFooter()
    {
    ?>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Papluz consulting Corp.<br>
                please see our<a href='legal.php'>legal information page</a>.
            </p>
        </footer>
        <?php
    }

    public function isUrlCurrentPage($url)
    {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $url) === false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function displayButton($name, $url, $active = true)
    {
        if ($active) {
        ?>
            <div class="menuitem">
                <a href="<?= $url ?>">
                    <img src='/data/img/arrow_white.svg' width="20" height="20">
                    <span class='menutext'><?= $name ?></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <div class="menuitem">
                <!-- <img src='/data/img/arrow_white.svg'> -->
                <span class='menutext'><?= $name ?></span>
            </div>
<?php
        }
    }
}
```

The class by itself is not important, but the attempt to infer it from `Reflection` class is:

*foo.php*:

```
<?php
require_once('page.php');
$class = new Reflection('Page');
echo '<pre>'.$class.'</pre>';
```

gives error:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Reflection could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/2/foo.php on line 5
```

So the error says the `Reflection` class does not have the method `__toString()`, but since it is in the book as example, I assume it should. So how to echo the variable `$class`, which is infered `Page` class via `Reflaction` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This book and the example is very outdated and it's not recommended developing like this in 2020. The code is full of XSS security issues and bad code style. Anyway, you can try this here to reflect the class:

```php
<?php

// ...

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Page');

$properties = $reflector->getProperties();

foreach($properties as $property)
{
    echo $property->getName() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I haven't found any better book covering also mysql. The book is 5-years old, yes it is old, but there are very few php-books nowdays, cause no-one uses php today.

Comment: You can try to read https://phptherightway.com/ and "Modern PHP" from Josh Lockhart. This page is also a good start [Learn modern PHP](https://odan.github.io/learn-php/). I also have written some [blog posts](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html) about this topic.